# Git pull using python skript

Tags: python, git, raspberry-pi, gitlab, ssh-keys

I am trying to write an update function for a remote raspberry which I won't direct acesss to. Meaning I have a webserver which sends command over post requests. When I want to make changes to the code of the raspberry I send him "update" as an response of the raspberry asking "nextInstruction".

Now I want the raspberry to git clean and git pull.

my general communications.py:

```
#code beforhand
elif (decodedresponse['responseInfo']['data'][1]['command'] == "update"):

        subprocess.call("./update.sh", shell=True)

        #update
        #os.system('sudo git clean -f -d')
        #os.system('git pull')
        #os.system('sudo reboot')
#code after
```

my update.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo git clean -f -d
git pull
sudo reboot
```

The problem:
If I execute the update.sh directly it works. When I run the python script apparently he doesn't get the ssh keys in ~/.ssh.

How can I attach the ssh key to my python script? Do I even understand the problem?
Is there an easier solution for logging in into my remote gitlab repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather let my bash script run the python script, and decide the action/job by pythons exit code. Here is an example.

**Note**: calling `sudo` may require a password to enter, unless you edit your sudoers file (`visudo`) and add an exception for this user running the script and git.

**p.py** (make sure py file has shebang (first line) and `chmod +x` attrib set.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# instead of  >>subprocess.call("./update.sh", shell=True)
exit(100)
```

**update.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

$(./p.py)
JOB=$?  # get pythons exitcode here

if [ $JOB -eq 100 ]; then
    echo "update"
elif [ $JOB -eq 50 ]; then
    echo "delete";
else
    echo "nothing"
fi
```

Comment: so my update skript watches for the exit code of my python skrict and starts the git commands when it exits? Could work, I am trying it out. Thanks